# Check if the application is inactive in the foreground mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, foreground

I can check if my application is in the `foreground` or `background` mode through the `AppDelegate`. I want now to check if the application is inactive even it's in the `foreground` mode. In other words, I want to check that the user is not using the app even if it is in the foreground. Is there any way to do it from the `AppDelegate`? Is there any other way for the check?

Comment: What do you mean with "inactive" exactly?

Comment: @MarcoPace I mean that the application is in the foreground for a long time and the user is not using it

Comment: Doesn't exists anything exactly like that: the closest one is the UIApplicationWillResignActive notification, posted when application loses focus. As an alternative you can check the UIApplicationStateInactive, which means that the app is running in the foreground but is not receiving events.
If you want something to check when the user leave the app opened and does nothing, I'm afraid you should implement it by yourself.

Comment: @MarcoPace where can I do the check of  `UIApplicationStateInactive` please?

Comment: @Llg there is no way to get an **IDLE** state of your app.

Comment: You can check the applicationState: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623003-applicationstate

Answer (score 0):

There is `UIApplicationStateInactive` state in `UIApplicationState` that serves exactly that purpose.

Comment: The `UIApplicationStateInactive` will work even if the application is in the foreground mode?

Comment: I want to check that the user is not using the app even if it is in the foreground

Comment: Yes, like when the iOS overlay is shown, or you double tap the home button, or another app is in the foreground in iPad's overlay.

Comment: where can I check this? Is it from the AppDelegate? Have I to use a timer to check every time when the app is already in the foregroud?

Comment: You will receive `applicationWillResignActive` in runtime from `AppDelegate` or check on demand the `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState]`